# Cannot log into Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

During the last few weeks I couldn't log into the stackoverflow.com page using my Internet connection from my [Internet service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) (ISP) - the error is in the snapshot below.

Though, when trying to use 3G connection shared via USB tethering/hotspot from my smartphone, I can get through.

What is going on? Is it something related to firewall from the ISP?

[image]

Comment: You will have to ask your ISP to see what is going on.

Comment: Would be nice to know what's behind the “details” link. Also: Can you ping *SO*, or even open a connection with `nc` on port 80? Maybe you have changed your proxy settings in Chrome.

Comment: or may be DNS Cache issue, flush DNS and try again

Comment: @Ixg I can ping SO. I use no proxy for Chrome. May you guide me how to 'open connection with nc on port 80' ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I tried DNS flush and the issue remains. I guess it is on the ISP side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is caused by my ISP (internet service provider).
After making contact with them, they fixed their router(s) and the issue is resolved.

Thank you every one!